# How to handle drag and drop in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, multi-touch

I am a fresher in this android field,i am facing an issue in my new project which is mainly dealing with graphics,where i have to drag and drop the shapes in canvas(shapes like rectangle,ellipse etc),i am using android version 2.1,please give me some nice suggestions or sample codes to deal with this functionality

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would my helper for you. Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/DragAndDropDemo.html)

Regards.